# 2 user space programs over tun using multicast

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, multicast, qemu, yocto

I am still getting my hands-on with networking programming for linux and please feel free to clear my understanding if you feel its vague or incorrect.

Query:

I have baked a Linux image using yocto project which is similar to core-image-minimal. This part is irrelevant for the query. I boot this image using QEMU emulator and when QEMU is booted up it creates a sudo interface by the name tap0. The IP of the QEMU is 192.168.7.2 and tap0 i guess has IP 192.168.7.1.

Now I have another user space program written in simple C which tries to listen whatever the QEMU program(node) is sending. So, I use a fragment similar to this:

```
if ( (fd = open("/dev/net/tun",O_RDWR)) < 0) PERROR("open");

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
ifr.ifr_flags = TUNMODE;
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "w-tap%d", IFNAMSIZ);
if (ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr) < 0) PERROR("ioctl");

printf("Allocated interface %s. Configure and use it\n", ifr.ifr_name);

s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
sin.sin_port = htons(PORT);
if ( bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) PERROR("bind");

fromlen = sizeof(from);
while(1) {
    l = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen);
    //print the data etc
}
```

Now If I start this C code with say `sudo ./tun_proxy 1534`, I am able to listen the messages on this port sent by 192.168.7.2.

Further,

I Boot up QEMU with additional option `-net socket,mcast=224.244.224.245:30490` since baked image has a small program in it to send some messages as broadcast on the multicast group and port. Also, I should be able to listen these message on the previous tun_proxy application. I even created a new thread in that which tries to listen on the multicast group but I get the error message as "already in use"

Where exactly is my understanding wrong? All I need is 2 user space programs, one of which is a QEMU to communication via multicast messages.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is sound, there are just 2 problems you need to address:

- If you bind on `INADDR_ANY` you are blocking the port for all other addresses (including multicast) unless you use `REUSEADDR`. Your `INADDR_ANY` bound socket would also be receiving the multicast it is blocking access to, except:
- Some socket on a "host" needs to use `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` where the membership request matches the traffic before any sockets will receive the multicast traffic.

## Emulating your current example:

As an equivalent but rather bizarre example, `shell1` is equivalent to your listener and `shell2` shows that a seemingly unrelated socket's ip-add-membership (but for the correct address and all interfaces) causes it to receive traffic:

```
shell1$ socat UDP-RECVFROM:30490,bind=0.0.0.0 EXEC:date

shell2$ echo hi | socat UDP-DATAGRAM:224.244.224.245:30490 STDIO
shell1$ (socat is still waiting for a packet)

shell2-add-membership$ socat UDP-RECVFROM:1044,reuseaddr,bind=127.0.0.1,ip-add-membership=224.244.224.245:0.0.0.0 EXEC:date&
       [1] 16003 
shell2$ echo hi | socat UDP-DATAGRAM:224.244.224.245:30490 STDIO
       Thu Sep  1 00:16:28 CEST 2016
shell1$ (socat now exits cleanly)
```

## Fixing it for multicast:

So to run 2+ clients, the correct method would be:

```
shellclient1$ socat UDP-RECVFROM:30490,bind=0.0.0.0,reuseaddr,ip-add-membership=224.244.224.245:0.0.0.0 EXEC:date
shellclient2$ socat UDP-RECVFROM:30490,bind=0.0.0.0,reuseaddr EXEC:date
...
shellclientn$ socat UDP-RECVFROM:30490,bind=0.0.0.0,reuseaddr EXEC:date


shell2$ echo hi | socat UDP-DATAGRAM:224.244.224.245:30490 STDIO
       Thu Sep  1 00:16:28 CEST 2016
       ...
```

Notice that all must use SO_REUSEADDR, but only one must add membership.

[Qemu's socket network uses `SO_REUSEADDR`](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=net/socket.c;h=5cd0b9abf7e8d7299c7454d9650827468b8b9e64;hb=23ddf2bb1e4bfe2b72a726fe5e828807b65941ad#l176) and does an membership. So the code blocking the socket is probably other code that needs to be modified to be like Qemu.

Comment: I tried to use the shell1 program as a means to listen to the multicast messages sent by the QEMU. QEMU was booted with same -net socket,mcast=224.244.224.245:30490 options. Although, the shell1 program returns an error : Address already in use. Also, one interesting difference that I noticed is that when QEMU is started with the multicast option, no tap network interface is created. Although, when I use a standard command like "runqemu qemux86 my-image", it creates a virtual interface. How can I start QEMU with multicast option and also virtual network interface?

Comment: I don't think you can use socket's options on other network types. But you would want to make sure you use reuseaddr and it is on all the sockets using port 30490. My first example was how to emulate your current situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to listen to multicast messages using reuseaddr option.

Comment: @HimanshuP2 hopefully you can explain to yourself how it is working, if so you can use socket.c around Lines 174 and 198 to implement the code you need and eliminate -net socket. If you are still having trouble with add_membership look at `netstat -gn` output with and without the QEMU socket.